# PlusMinus definition unexpectedly affects plotting

Tags: plotting, evaluation, symbols

In version 10.1 I found a strange [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) behavior I did not anticipate.  It seems that various heads including [`PlusMinus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlusMinus.html) are treated as wrappers and stripped by `Plot` in a way that is not safe.  This means that definitions that do not appear in the plot expression can radically and errantly affect its output:

```
ClearAll[PlusMinus]
Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
PlusMinus = Power;
Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Surely this is a bug?  What versions are affected?  What is the easiest way to patch this in version 10.1?

Comment: _v9.0.1_ is not affected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpBYU.png. Persisting through _v12.1_. (Tested on Wolfram cloud. )

Comment: I think this may be the function that needs leak-proofing: ``Charting`ParserDump`plotStripWrappers``

Comment: Bug also present in v11.2.

Comment: Further check shows `Charting\`ParserDump\`` context doesn't seem to exist in _v9.0.1_.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that [`PlusMinus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlusMinus.html) is the only wrapper that is not [`Protected`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html):

```
Charting`PlotParser; (* preload *)

Select[Charting`ParserDump`$pAllWrappers, FreeQ[Protected]@*Attributes]
```

> ```
> {PlusMinus}
> ```

We can remove it from that list to correct *this* bug, but perhaps induce others:

```
Charting`PlotParser; (* preload; do not remove! *)

With[{ov := OwnValues @ Charting`ParserDump`$pAllWrappers},
  ov = DeleteCases[ov, HoldPattern[PlusMinus], {3}];
]
```